# "Unknown Options" Error for AWS CLI w/ EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am attempting to test the creation of a spot instance from the CLI (on Windows). I am following the CLI documentation precisely as far as I can tell but I keep receiving an "unknown options" error as follows:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price 0.04 --type persistent 
--availability-zone us-east-1a 
--block-device-mapping "/dev/sdb=snap-ec0f8df5::false" ami-e55a7e8c
Unknown options: --block-device-mapping, ami-e55a7e8c, /dev/sdb=snap-ec0f8df5::false
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong... Thanks for you help!

Comment: This looks right to me. I'd be concerned about the two colons in the parameter under the Windows shell, but the Amazon docs say specifically that's okay provide you've quoted it, as you have. Try changing the order of the parameters to see if it changes which ones are bad. Try removing one parameter at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ultimately found that at the time, there were separate CLI tools for AWS in general & EC2.